# Question about approximating measurable functions with continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, measurable-functions

I faced the following question:

Prove that every Lebesgue measurable function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a limit almost everywhere of a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous functions. Is it always possible to choose this sequence to be monotone?

I have proved the first part but I am not sure about the second part. I believe it is not always possible to choose this sequence to be monotone but I don't have any example. (I am thinking about [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function)).

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: consider a measurable $f$ with $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty$